# Multiple - isolated - WkWebViews in the same app - macOS

Tags: cocoa, wkwebview

Let's say I want to show two WkWebView side by side, each logged in to the same website, but with two different accounts. The logins (and other data) should be persisted between launches

According to this 2017 wwdc talk, it can be done. This is the result I get: they share data.

[image]

And this is what I want, not sharing data.

[image]

According to the speaker, it's possible. He just doesn't say how.

A few approaches I've tried

**Instantiating a new `WkWebView`**. That made no difference. They still share data. I tried instantiating both from a storyboard and in code.

**Changing my bundle identifier**. Not a viable solution as I want the two datastores to run side by side. But it works, and also it seems the data (sans cookies) is stored in `/Users/username/Library/WebKit/(bundle-identifier)`

**Instantiating a new `WKProcessPool`** with `webView.configuration.processPool = WKProcessPool()`. Made no difference.

**Handling cookies myself**. This would be my last resort. I'd set the `WKWebsiteDataStore` to be the `.nonPersistent()` one, and save and delete cookies in my own store on open and close (the cookie observer doesn't trigger in `nonPersistent`). Bad in three ways: 1. I need a secure place to store them - (Keychain)? 2. It won't persist whatever the sites may have in Local Storage, 3: added work and complexity

Comment: I tried the `.nonPersistent()` route. It works. But it turns out that ALL WKWebViews using `.nonPersistent()` actually share datta. So while I can now show two WKWebViews logged into the same website in with two different accounts, it seems impossible to log in to a third account.

Comment: It seems this is indeed possible in the same app, if the webviews don't share WKProcessPool. My problem is that I'm trying to do this across app instances, ie multiple instances of the same app. It seems there's some internal logic that says "first instance of a wkwebview gets this pool, second gets that pool", and that those "first instance" are indeed shared across app instances

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, still looking

Comment: Are you sure `nonPersistent` shares data? we use `nonPersistent` to keep our tabs (implemented by multiple wkwebviews) isolated and it works fine. Are you reusing a `nonPersistent` result? each time you call `nonPersistent`, it creates a brand new store in memory.